XAct website not working
I am unable to download xAct can someone help ? The website for xAct is not opening, is there any other way I can download it ?

The service provider where I host xAct implemented some changes earlier in August and the xAct web got broken in the process. I hope to get it running again soon. If you need to download anything, please contact me at jose@xact.es .

Main page of xAct
Wayback Machine archived main page of xAct:
https://web.archive.org/web/20230320122045/http://xact.es/index.html
Download
Use the download link URL provided by Wayback Machine to download:
https://web.archive.org/web/20230317212020/http://xact.es/download/xAct_1.2.0.zip
https://web.archive.org/web/20230317212020/http://xact.es/download/xAct_1.2.0.tgz
Install
Assuming you are using Windows OS,
Wolfram Mathematica -> File -> Install
Type of Item to Install: Application
Source:   the xAct_1.2.0.zip file

Test
ClearAll["Global`*"];
<< xAct`xTensor`;
DefManifold[M3, 3, {a, b, c, d, e}]
DefTensor[v[a], M3]
DefTensor[F[-a, -b], M3, Antisymmetric[{-a, -b}]]
F[-a, -b]  v[b]
Simplification[%]
F[-a, -d]  v[d]  v[b]  v[-b] + 
 3  v[b]  v[c]  v[-c]  F[-b, d]  F[-d, -a]
% // Simplification
DefCovD[Cd[-a], {";", "\[Del]"}]
Cd[-a][F[-b, -c]  v[c]]


